# Show that NP∩coNP =∅

Tags: np, co-np

I know that P is a subset of NP, but I'm not sure what this tells me about P as it relates to coNP?
I feel like this is how I should go about proving it, but I'm not sure how. Otherwise, I could find a language that is in both NP and coNP, but I'm not sure how to prove any examples of that.

I know that I can prove L and L complement both exists in P and therefore NP, but I don't know how to relate this to coNP.

Comment: I think you need to carefully look at the definition of $coNP$ again - your second paragraph suggests you can show that $P \subseteq NP \cap coNP$ (which would be a correct statement).

Comment: @LukeMathieson, *incorrect* [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/121834/show-that-np∩conp-∅#comment256346_121834), surely?  (I'm not quite sure that that's what the second paragraph says, though.)

Comment: Please check the title: did you intend P∩coNP =∅?

Comment: PRIME is both in NP and co-NP. As is COMPOSITE. (Which is taken as an argument that they are both unlikely to be NO-complete)

Answer (score 2):

Read the definition of NP and co-NP. By that definition, every problem in P is automatically both in NP and co-NP. There’s nothing to prove, that’s how they are defined.